# QtCreator: use scp within Custom Process Step

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to setup Qt in such a way that the **sources** or rather the whole project directory will be copied using `scp` as Custom Process Step within the Deployment. The sources will be translated later by the target machine itself. At the terminal this works well:

```
setsid scp -r . <user>@<host>:<path>
```

`setsid` asks for the password needed by ssh with a graphical prompt.

1. What is the correct parameter to get the project path as working directory?
2. How to avoid the following error?

   ```
   Could not start process "setsid scp -r . <user>@<host>:<path>"
   Error while building/deploying project MyProject (kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.0 GCC 64bit2)
   When executing step "Custom Process Step"
   ```

The current settings of Custom Process Step:

- Command: `setsid scp -r . <user>@<host>:<path>`
- Arguments: *left empty*
- Working directory: `%{buildDir}` *I know - this is wrong*

Comment: how you designed the "Custom Process Step"?

Comment: @MohammadKanan see edit

Comment: Try modify the command to be fully qualified, lets say in your linux `setsid` is located in `/path/setsid`, then use :  `/path/setsid scp -r . <user>@<host>:<path>`

Comment: this results in the same error :(

Comment: ok, one more , put your command in a shell script, make sure your script runs at command line, then use the script fully qualified in the Custom build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my working setting:

### Deployment

- Command:
  `setsid`
- Arguments:
  `scp -r . user@<host>:<path>`
- Working directory:
  `%{CurrentProject:Path}`

When hit the Build button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), a prompt asks for the password needed by `scp`, then the files will copied as specified in Arguments and in Working directory. In this case, the whole project folder will be copied.

### Run

- Command:
  `setsid`
- Arguments:
  `ssh -t user@<host> <command>`
- Working directory:
  `.`

When hit the Run button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), a prompt asks for the password needed by `ssh`, then the `command` will executed as specified in Arguments.

The point is, that Qt-Creator expects a return value from the command. In this case the command is `setsid`.